# java.awt.HeadlessException: No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it

Tags: java, swing, unix, exception

I tried a simple java program to show dialog box. It's working in Windows systems.

```
package test;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class JPane {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int dialogButton = JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION;
        int dialogResult = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog (null, "Would You Like to Save your Previous Note First?","warning",dialogButton,JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        if(dialogResult == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
            System.out.println("Yes");
        }
        else
            System.out.println("No");
    }
}
```

But when i tried the same code in unix environment it's showing the following exception:

> java.awt.HeadlessException:
>   No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
>           at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:207)
>           at java.awt.Window.(Window.java:535)
>           at java.awt.Frame.(Frame.java:420)
>           at java.awt.Frame.(Frame.java:385)
>           at javax.swing.SwingUtilities$SharedOwnerFrame.(SwingUtilities.java:1759)

I tried setting DISPLAY env variable through putty. But still same exception.